# Open website passing local image as argument

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file

## Problem definition

I am trying to open a website by its url providing an image stored on the user's computer as an argument using windows batch. The path of the image on the user's computer is an argument of the batch file.

```
my-batch-file.bat C:\path\to\image1 C:\path\to\image2
```

would open www.example.com making these two images available to the JS script.

### Concrete example:

I own the website www.image-edition-example.com where people can open images to edit them.

I want them to be able to load the images they want to edit to the website using the batch script. The images are stored on the user's computer at path `C:\path\to\image1` and `C:\path\to\image2`. I (ideally) don't want to involve any back-end and just want to load the image in the front-end.

## What I've tried so far

From what I understand, it is not possible to access user's filesystem from JS in the browser (sounds a fair security choice).

I could also open the image in the bash (in base64 for instance, I have no idea how it could be done) and send it with a cURL request.

In this case, I can either send it via POST, and in this case I would have to access to the data on server side, but my website is a static website built with Webpack so I don't know how I can access it and send it back to the front.

The other option would be using GET, which means putting base64 images into the url, which makes the URL too long !

Does anyone know how I can get around this issue ?

Comment: unclear how opening up a url and making images available makes any sense. What exactly are you trying to do? Upload an image to a site through bash?

Comment: yes, it is quite hard to explain. Uploading an image to a site through bash could be a good sum up, but I also would like to access it in the front-end before it's sent. Does this make more sense ?

Comment: What front end? I was with you on the submit from bash part, but then...?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use something like selenium

Comment: Are you trying to send it to **your** website or someone else's?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  Yes, it's my website, so I can modify things there too.

Comment: Have you considered creating an app instead? An electron app, or a Windows Store app with html+js, can both access and upload local files the way you want.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve. Currently your question tells us that you're opening a URL and using JScript but you've only provided us with a command showing that you're running a `my-batch-file.bat` file and passing it two arguments, each being an image, `C:\path\to\image1` as `%1` and `C:\path\to\image2` as `%2`. If you need help with the content of the [tag:batch-file], or with the [tag:jscript] we need to see that code, and a full explanation of how that code is failing to work as written and intended.

Comment: What do you expect to do with it when your website page loads? Sending an image to it via GET won't in any way store it on the site. For that you need server-side code or WebDAV or similar.

Comment: @TKoL: yes, I already have an electron app which does the job and opens images properly, I was just wondering if it was feasible for users that did not install the app to open the website with images saved on the disk

Comment: Not without a file select and/or drag-and-drop I don't think.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no, the difficulty is not to save it to the website's server. The issue is to open it in the browser. For instance, you could say "I want to open this image to edit it on an image editing website", the image is stored locally. For this, you run the batch script to open the image directly in the website and have it ready to edit. No back-end involved

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the question is:

- You want to run a batch process from the command line
- It will identify local images by their filename that it should send on to a page on your website
- Your website is static, no server-side component available
- Converting the images to Base64 or similar to include them in the URL would result in URLs that were too long
- The page you're opening will interact with the image locally (not storing it on a server or similar)

I can't think of a way to do that with a conventional web browser.

The closest I can think of is to have a small application running locally that makes it possible for browser-based code on your website to read a local image, using CORS to whitelist your website's origin so that ajax isn't blocked by the browser's Same Origin Protocol implementation.

For instance, suppose as part of its processing for a specific image, your tool:

1. Copied the relevant image (say, `foo.jpg`) to `C:\PublicImages`
2. Triggered the URL `http://www.example.com/page.html?image=foo.jpg` or similar.
3. Code on that page would query `http://localhost:3000/foo.jpg` to request the image data via ajax.
4. A tiny web server process that you'd only run when running this task responded to that request with the image data for that image in `C:\PublicImages`.

Any reasonable simple HTTP server would be able to do it. Or if you prefer writing a bit of code rather than configuring some random server package, you could write your own using Node.js and (perhaps) [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/). It would look something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const options = {
    extensions: [/*...relevant image extensions here...*/],
    index: false,
    redirect: false,
    setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");
        // ...and probably other CORS headers...
    }
};

app.use(express.static("C:\\PublicImages", options));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Serving images on port ${port}`));
```

That's just a sketch.

Comment: This is very inventive. I'm implementing this and I'll check your answer when it works. Thank you for your help.